# Heroku deploy taking extremely long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have deployed to Heroku many times but, its never taken this long. It stops at `Running: rake assets:precompile` at then just pauses.

Any ideas to make it deploy as fast as it used to?

I think it has something to do with the fact that I just updated to rails 3.2.12

Comment: Your question is very unlikely to be solved since there are way too many factors that have to be considered and you provided zero of them. Least you could do is to find out the differences between fast-deploying apps and slow-deploying apps.

Comment: I did research on it prior to asking my question. I installed the turbo-sprockets gem but, it is still deploying slowly.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

When upgrading to 3.2.12

add this to your `Gemfile`

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby "1.9.3"
```

Heroku by default will use ruby "1.9.2" which is slower to precompile assets

Answer (score 1):

You can also try turbo-sprockets-rails3 gem (https://github.com/ndbroadbent/turbo-sprockets-rails3) which skips asset compilation stage if there is no changes in assets.